# Cross-browser horizontal scroll with flex box

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I've being trying to get a consistent horizontal scroll with flex-box.

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/NABzdQ

Things were going great, but I did that thing ~ where you forget to look at it in Safari and FireFox. Things aren't working great there. Normally, if something works in web-kit but not firefox, webkit is smoothing out something that isn't right / where as firefox follows the rules. So, it's not a bug or anything... but the flexy things aren't really expanding around their child images.

That being said, I can't figure out which part is the pivotal thing that needs to change.

1. I'm using flex-box for the header and 'content' area where the content area grows to fill the remaining space. So, a global column
2. Within the 'content' area, there is a list that is flex and row. In the list there are items with either text or an image. The images should be 100% height of the list, and then auto width.
3. I would have thought that I could set the images to 100% height and width auto (similar to how I do the opposite for small-screens) - but the affect is not the same.

   `img {
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
   }`
4. to deal with this, I use JS to find the height of the 'content' area and set the images to that height.

http://s.codepen.io/sheriffderek/debug/NABzdQ  (version with no editor for testing / on iPad etc.)

Works great in Chrome.

So... Does anyone have any advice? My real project is small-screen first, so more complex - but this is a clear example of where things go awry.

### Styles

```
ul
    list-style: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

body
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    height: 100vh // ?

.header
    // 

.section // content
    display: flex
    flex-grow: 1

.item-list
    display: flex
    flex-direction: row
    flex-grow: 1
    max-width: 100%
    overflow: auto
.item
    display: flex
    flex-grow: 1
a //
    display: block
    display: flex
.image-w
    width: auto // should stretch to fit the child / image
    max-height: 100%
    overflow: hidden //?
    img
        display: block
        width: auto
        // height to be set by JS

.text-w
    width: 400px
    padding: 1rem
```

### Scripts

```
var setUp = function() {
    $('.item').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // var $thisFigure = $this.find('.image-w');
        var $thisImage = $this.find('img');
        var thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        $thisImage.css({
            height: thisHeight
        });
    });
};

$(window).resize( setUp ).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: One way to get the images to occupy the full available height is to apply `display: flex` to the parent (in this case, `.image-w`). That activates `align-items: stretch` on the children..

Comment: Also, I've noticed before that *placeholder images* can render differently than actual images ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38481395/3597276)). Consider testing with real images, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `display: flex` on the image parents can get their height in order, but that doesn't account for their ratios. Weird about the placeholder image reference, but certainly not the issue here. Here's an example with your suggestion: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/vKVkkP  as you can see, everything gets whack.